# Probability calculator

Tags: probability

Hi guys I am trying to solve a small problem but I really don't know how to go about doing it. It works a bit like a slot machine...Basically you need to get 3 in a row. But it can also be diagonal.

```
- - -
X X X
- - - 

X - -
- X -
- - X

- - X
- X -
X - -
```

These are the possible outcomes...where X is the option and - is any option that which can be X as well...I'm hoping you guys understand what I mean...just like a slot machine

```
Option 1 6 times
Option 2 12 times
Option 3 18 times
Option 4 24 times
Option 5 30 times
Option 6 36 times
Option 7 42 times
```

I want to know what are the odds of each option would be...so there is a total of 168 occurrences in total what is the odds of winning each option?

Thanks for any help!

**edit

I basically want to know what are the odds of each option appearing 3 times in a row.
Each time 9 options will be selected. They are considered 3 times in a row if they are in the middle line or diagonally. But not the top 2 lines. There are 168 possible things that can appear....I guess picture it as a bag with 168 balls, each option is a type of ball...so option 7 is in the bag 42 times. 9 balls are taken out each time. 3 at a time which form 1 column at a time.

Comment: I cannot understand this question at all. Can you write out a small example, where you can write out the entire problem? Or maybe find a mathematician to talk to, to help put your problem into comprehensible form?

Comment: Does my edit help a little bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Maybe* I understand the problem now. I'll do the Option 2 case, you ought to see how to do the others.

The probability of getting any one of the three winning patterns with Option 2 is $$a={12\over168}\,{11\over167}\,{10\over166}$$ So the probability of winning with Option 2 is $3a$ --- almost. Trouble is, you could have more than one of the three patterns, and you don't want to count that twice. So, you have to subtract the probability of having two winning patterns. For any two of the patterns, that's $$b={12\over168}\,{11\over167}\,{10\over166}\,{9\over165}\,{8\over164}$$ and there are three ways to have two winning patterns, so we are down to $3a-3b$. But we've now undercounted the situations where we have all three winning patterns. This has probability $$c={12\over168}\,{11\over167}\,{10\over166}\,{9\over165}\,{8\over164}\,{7\over163}\,{6\over162}$$ so the final answer is $3a-3b+c$.

The same idea will work with any of the options (except that since option 1 appears only 6 times we can't get all three winning patterns of option 1). The technical name for what I've done here is "the principle of inclusion-exclusion".